# Transparent SMTP relay for hiding sender IP

Tags: smtp, smarthost

I'm looking to create my own mailserver, however I cannot have it working on my main server because it is in a home network. I want to hide my home IP by routing all mail (inbound and outbound) through a VPS. How can I accomplish this?

I've attempted using some SMTP smarthost Docker images, all of which are based on Postfix. For the most part, if outbound email gets through, inbound doesn't because of authentication failure. Without authentication, anyone would be able to use my relay, which I wish to avoid.